# The artifact has been relocated to

Tags: eclipse, selenium, maven, allure

I've an automation testing project which runs by Maven and, I want to add in it an Allure report.

I've added the required dependencies but I get the following warning:

What this means and how can I resolve this ?

> The artifact xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2 has been relocated to
> xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2

What is this means and how can I resolve it?

**RESULT**
[image]

**XML**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>auto</groupId>
  <artifactId>auto</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <distributionManagement>
    <relocation>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <message>https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-244</message>
    </relocation>
  </distributionManagement>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>AdvancedSelenium</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.7</aspectj.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.automatedowl/allure-environment-writer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.automatedowl</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-environment-writer</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build> 
        <plugins>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <allure.results.directory>${basedir}/target/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
                        <allure.link.issue.pattern>https://example.org/issue/{}</allure.link.issue.pattern>
                        <allure.link.tms.pattern>https://example.org/tms/{}</allure.link.tms.pattern>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <testng.dtd.http>true</testng.dtd.http>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-maven -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This message means that the groupId/artifactId of a dependency (in this case a plugin) has been changed. I would first suggest to upgrade the plugin `allure-maven` to most recent version and check if the warning will not there anymore.. if it keeps open an issue on the code repo of the plugin...

Answer (score -1):

Actually the allure report was not opened because of Firewall block of the antivirus.
After disabling the firewall the report runs despite the Warning message at cmd. [image]